# Oauth with same credentials and multiple sessions

Tags: session, oauth-2.0, oauth, sap-commerce-cloud, bearer-token

I am working on an eCommerce Website and an App. We use SAP Hybris for OAuth 2.0.
To get an access token I send a Cliend ID, Client secret, Username and Password to the auth server.

**Problem Example:**

If I log in with the App first and then the Website, I won't be able to refresh my token in one of the sessions.

The token I receive from the server is pretty standard and looks like this:

```
{
"access_token":"9T7IziRSIM_QIqFtttM8rhf83zU",
"token_type":"bearer",
"refresh_token":"MztkOmh67gIEiMwX5sED-Rug51c",
"expires_in":43199,
"scope":"basic"
}
```

The only difference is that in the "Website Token" the `expires_in` would have a lower value than `43199` since it was requested after the "App Token".

Since both the `access_token` as well as the `refresh_token` are identical, the moment one of them expire and we try to fetch a new token the first session that does it will receive completely different credentials. As soon as the second session (which is now expired) tries to also refresh it's credentials the server will deny new credentials since the old credentials can be used only once to get new tokens.

Every 12 hours the tokens become expired and the first client to request a new token effectively logs out the other client by doing so.

**Question:**

What could I do to deal with this problem?

I was thinking it should be possible to send a unique ID to my request to generate a unique token. However I cannot find any information about this on the SAP Docs.